# Iron Router data fires 3 times

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I have this route set up with a loding template on Router.Config

```
Router.onBeforeAction('loading');
this.route('clients', {
    path: '/clients',
    template: 'clientsAll',
    waitOn: function () {
        return Meteor.subscribe('clientsAll');
    },
    data: function () {
        if (this.ready()) {
            console.log("Data");
            return Clients.find().fetch();
        }
    }
});
```

Everything works fine it displays the loading template before rendering the template, but on the log it shows data being fired twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a normal behavior, `data` like most route methods is run inside a reactive computation.

In your `data` method you depend on `this.ready()` which happens to be a reactive data source (it returns the state of the wait list returned by `waitOn`).

So basically this is what is going on :

- your data method is declared as a computation and initially runs with `this.ready()` returning false.
- the subscription you wait on becomes ready some time in the future so `this.ready()` now returns true and your `data` method is rerun.

This is not a problem because `data` methods are usually not computational heavy (they just return some data that is available locally on the client).

Comment: OK I debug the script and it acutally runs 3 times the first time like you said it returns false so nothing get print out on the log. Then a second a time which returns true and prints out on the console log and finally a third time which also prints out again on the log.

Comment: `Clients.find().fetch()` is reactive too (cursors obtained from collections are reactive data sources), maybe this explains the 3rd rerun, try console.logging it.

Comment: I took out Clients.find().fetch() and made data return an empy array and it still gets run 3 times

Comment: So I got rid of `Router.onBeforeAction('loading');` and data is now ony being run twice like is expected. But I need to show a placeholder before or else it renders a empty template and then a second later it gets populated with data. I also tried do it on the action: but same results

Comment: @AndreEscudero, change your data function so it just returns `Clients.find().fetch()` (is a call to fetch really necessary in your case?), use the loading hook and make sure you provide a `loadingTemplate` for the route (`this.route('clients', {path: '/clients', loadingTemplate: 'waiting'})`).

Comment: @PeppeL-G alright so it seems there is no way to overcome this. Data still gets fired twice even after following your suggestion.Running Clients.find().fetch() and I will possibly be adding more fetchs and it will get more complex. Would running that code twice have any impact?

Comment: There is no impact on calling your `data` method multiple times because it's not CPU effective as it's simply returning results from the local client-side subset of the database that has already been fetched on the server ONCE. The subscription occuring on the server does the heavy work, once it's sent down to the client you can query directly minimongo, usually with straightforward queries. Also, your method has no side effect so it is safe to run it accidentally more than what is actually useful.