# Meteor - data fetched multiple times?

Tags: meteor, coffeescript, iron-router, meteor-collection2

I'm using Meteor Admin project stub (https://github.com/yogiben/meteor-admin).

I amended my data - `posts` collection in `main.coffee` to include some custom filtering defined in `buildPostSearch` function:

```
Router.map ->

    //cut 

    @route "dashboard",
        path: "/dashboard"
        waitOn: ->
          [
            subs.subscribe 'posts'
          ]
        data: ->
            posts: Posts.find( buildPostSearch() ).fetch()

buildPostSearch = () ->
    console.log "Executed."
    { //filter object constructed depending on Session parameters }
```

This works correctly, but it is being invoked multiple times on page refresh. I can see in browser console:

```
Executed.
Executed.
Executed.
Executed.
Executed.
Executed.
(...around 50 times)
```

I am worried about performance. Does it query DB so many times? Is there any better way to do it?

Comment: Are you sure the `waitOn` is not the cause? I mean it loops to check on the subscription, it does not run it each time

Answer (score 1):

The `data` hook is reactive, so it's perfectly normal for it to fire [multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25432476/iron-router-data-fires-3-times).

It's important to remember that when it runs it's fetching documents from **your local minimongo cache** and not from the actual database. Each of those `find` operations is actually taking a minuscule amount of time, so performance is not a concern.

As for why it's running so many times, I suspect that may have to do with the nature of `buildPostSearch`. As you note in the comments, `buildPostSearch` depends on session variables so each time one of them changes, your `data` hook will execute again.

Additional note: I think you mean `data: ->` and not `data ->` in your sample code.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You are right, there is `data: ->`